# Is it okay to inherit from an std::variant in order to make it recursive?

Tags: c++, std-variant

This question comes out of [a reddit thread about an Advent of Code problem from last year](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/zkmyh4/comment/j02mlen/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

I had mentioned that the only way to make an `std::variant` recursive was to wrap it in a `struct` so you can forward declare the `struct` as there is no way to forward declare an instantiation of a template, e.g.

```
struct wrapped_list;
using list = std::variant<int, std::vector<wrapped_list>>;
struct wrapped_list {
    list val;
};
```

Some other poster suggested using inheritance rather than composition:

```
class List;

class List : public std::variant<int, std::vector<List>> {  
  public:  
    using base = std::variant<int, std::vector<List>>;  
    using base::base;  
    using base::operator=;  
};
```

which is better in the sense that you do not have to deal with a wrapper `struct` that serves no purpose other than satisfying syntax requirements for declaring the variant.

However, I am used to never inheriting from types in the standard library. Is the above declaration portable and legal C++? Is calling `std::visit` on such a variant officially undefined behavior? etc.

Comment: Yes, looks legal to me. The manual for `std::visit` specifically mentions supporting types derived from `variant`.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I mistook `std::vector` for `std::variant`. I thought the `std::variant` had itself as a possible member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the above declaration portable and legal C++?

Yes.

> Is calling `std::visit` on such a variant officially undefined behavior?

No, there's no problem doing that. You could implement the visitor to call itself recursively for example:

```cpp
struct visitor {
    void operator()(int x) const { std::cout << x << '\n'; }
    
    void operator()(const std::vector<List>& l) const {
        for(auto& v : l) std::visit(*this, v);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/En7YK1T7n)

(The recursive visitor will be possible to simplify in C++23 with [deducing `this`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html))